# Finding Captcha control inside createuserwizard

Tags: c#, asp.net, captcha, createuserwizard

I am integrating a Captcha control inside a CreateUserWizard.

[I got the Captcha control sample code from this website here](http://archive.aspsnippets.com/post/2009/04/03/How-to-implement-Captcha-in-ASPNet.aspx)

As I wanted to do a validation for user's input based on the Captcha using an if.. else.. statement. 
However an error occured when I trying to get the Captcha control from the createuserwizard.

Here the is error :

```
The name 'Captcha1' does not exist in the current context
```

I had tried to get this control as a textbox, image, control but it was not successful.

Here is the code :

```
 <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server">
              <ContentTemplate>

 <tr>
                            <td class="style4">Answer:</td>
                            <td>
                                <cc1:CaptchaControl ID="Captcha1" runat="server"
                                 CaptchaBackgroundNoise="Medium" CaptchaLength="5"
                                 CaptchaHeight="55" CaptchaWidth="200"
                                 CaptchaLineNoise="None" CaptchaMinTimeout="5"
                                 CaptchaMaxTimeout="240" FontColor = "#FF33CC" CaptchaFontWarping="Medium" />

                                 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCaptcha" />

                            </td>
                        </tr>
 </ContentTemplate>

              </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
```

Behind code:

```
protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Control Captcha1 = (Control)CreateUserWizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Captcha1");
        TextBox txtCaptcha = (TextBox)CreateUserWizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("txtCaptcha");

            Captcha1.ValidateCaptcha(txtCaptcha.Text.Trim());//error occurred here

        if (Captcha1.UserValidated)//error occurred here
        {

     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to find the Controls inside the CreateUserWizard

TextBox txtCaptcha = (TextBox)CreateUserWizardStep1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("txtCaptcha");